# ¿Cómo guardar una imagen en la galería desde android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy haciendo una pequeña aplicación que me carga una imagen y le cambia el tamaño el problema viene después, quisiera que se guarde en una carpeta que se cree desde la aplicación y que sea visible desde la galería para las otras aplicaciones. Esto es lo que tengo

```
OutputStream fileOutStream = null;
           Uri uri;
           try {
               File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                       + File.separator + "imagenesguardadas" + File.separator);
               file.mkdirs();
               File directorioImagenes = new File(file, "queseyo2.png");
               uri = Uri.fromFile(directorioImagenes);
               fileOutStream = new FileOutputStream(directorioImagenes);
           } catch (Exception e) {
               Log.e("ERROR!", e.getMessage());
           }

           try {
               resized.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fileOutStream);
               fileOutStream.flush();
               fileOutStream.close();
           } catch (Exception e) {
               Log.e("ERROR!", e.getMessage());
           }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes hacer algo así, en el código explico en cada línea que voy haciendo:

```
     try {
            // externalStorage
            String ExternalStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator;
            // uri de la imagen seleccionada
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(ExternalStorageDirectory + "Download/imagenseleccionada.jpg"));
            //carpeta "imagenesguardadas"
            String rutacarpeta = "imagenesguardadas/";
            // nombre del nuevo png
            String nombre = "nuevo.png";

            // Compruebas si existe la carpeta "imagenesguardadas", sino, la crea
            File directorioImagenes = new File(ExternalStorageDirectory + rutacarpeta);
            if (!directorioImagenes.exists())
                directorioImagenes.mkdirs();

            // le pasas al bitmap la uri de la imagen seleccionada
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
            // pones las medidas que quieras del nuevo .png
            int bitmapWidth = 120; // para utilizar width de la imagen original: bitmap.getWidth();
            int bitmapHeight = 120; // para utilizar height de la imagen original: bitmap.getHeight();
            Bitmap bitmapout = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, bitmapWidth, bitmapHeight, false);
            //creas el nuevo png en la nueva ruta
            bitmapout.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, new FileOutputStream(ExternalStorageDirectory + rutacarpeta + nombre));

            // le pones parametros necesarios a la imagen para que se muestre en cualquier galería

            File filefinal = new File(ExternalStorageDirectory + rutacarpeta + nombre);

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "Titulo");
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "Descripción");
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis ());
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_ID, filefinal.toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).hashCode());
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME, filefinal.getName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()));
            values.put("_data", filefinal.getAbsolutePath());
            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            cr.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

            //

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage());
        }
```

Para que cualquier galería muestre la imagen no tenía ni idea, [pero he estado buscando y encontré esto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21258221/how-to-create-an-app-image-folder-to-show-in-android-gallery). He añadido al código de arriba como lo deberías de hacer en tu caso.

Recuerda que desde [**Android 5.0**, necesitas pedir los permisos, en este caso de almacenamiento](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)