# Como puedo guardar datos de una segunda Activity y mostrarla en el primer Activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Hola Chic@s una pregunta como puedo hacer que en un Texto plano y un ImageView guarden datos

por ejemplo
tengo un Activity en el cual tengo
1 ImageView , 1 TextView y un LinearLayout Onclick para editar los datos

despues tengo una segunda Activity con
1 Texto plano
 3 imagenes en un ImageView
  y un boton guardar

Alguien tiene alguna idea de como guardardarlos en Java?
Activity
  1
con la ImageView 
  1 TexView que muestra el nombre de usuario y al pinchar el LinearLayout envia al usuario a otra Activity para editar los datos

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#222020"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/columncolor"
        android:orientation="horizontal"

        android:padding="16dp"
        android:weightSum="9">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="81dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Ajustes"
            android:textAlignment="viewStart"
            android:textColor="#F3EFEF"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="627dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="59dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="4">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/title_us"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="#14000000"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView4"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:padding="6dp"
                    android:text="Editar Perfil"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/Us_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="61dp"
                android:Onclik="btnuser"
                android:background="#14FFFFFF"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                        android:id="@+id/profile_image"
                        android:layout_width="63dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="left"
                        android:src="@drawable/noimg_xds"
                        app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"
                        app:civ_border_width="2dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/username_txt"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="29dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="left"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                        android:text="Nombre de usuario"
                        android:textAlignment="textStart"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="15sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/user_txt"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="29dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="left"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                        android:text="Usuario"
                        android:textAlignment="textStart"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                </FrameLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#00FFFFFF"
            android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents"
            >

            <android.support.design.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
                android:id="@+id/nav_bottom"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:background="#D81B60"

                android:backgroundTint="@color/columncolor"
                android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                app:fabAlignmentMode="center" />

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fabs"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_search"
                app:layout_anchor="@id/nav_bottom">

            </android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton>

        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity 2
 
Un Texto plano con un boton para guardar los datos que ingresa el usuario
2 ImageView que al pincharla se añade la imagen de perfil en el Activity 1

````
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="360dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="text" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="91dp"
                android:layout_height="112dp"
                tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars[0]" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="91dp"
                android:layout_height="108dp"
                tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars[1]" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```
````

Comment: Guardalos donde? En el dispositivo movil? o en un servidor de backend?

Comment: @solamente guardarlo en la app osea que se guarde como un dato persistente osea que se se mantenga los datos de manera local y se compartan entre activitys por ejemplo tengo un <string name="user">Usuario</string> y que al pinchar el boton guardar el dato usuario se cambie con el dato puesto por el usuario

Comment: Tienes 2 opciones o lo guardas persistente en BBDD o en Shared Preferences.

Comment: y tienes idea de como hacerlo? no tengo idea de como se hace @solamente

Comment: Busca información sobre como guardar en persistencia en Android hay mil tutoriales no es complicado animate a probarlo y si surgen problemas la comunidad te ayudara a resolverlos.

Comment: @solamente muchas gracias encontre uno, ahora falta encontrar uno que guarde la imagen al hacer Onclick y la muestre en el activity 1

Comment: la imagen se guarda en la memoria interna o en una sd card, obtienes el path y este es el que se guarda en SharedPreferences https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/33324/guardar-im%c3%a1genes-en-android-studio,  https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/107670/c%c3%b3mo-guardar-una-imagen-en-la-galer%c3%ada-desde-android-studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te dejo un ejemplo de como guardar imágenes en la SD si te surge alguna duda no dudes en preguntar.

**Añade los permisos necesarios en el manifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

**Código para el guardado de la imagen, primero selecciona la ruta y luego la comprime y la guarda:**

```
BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) iv_imagen.getDrawable();
Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();

File directorioSD = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File imagen= new File(directorioSD, "imagen1.png");

FileOutputStream outStream;
try {
    outStream = new FileOutputStream(imagen);
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream); 
    outStream.flush();
    outStream.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias :D, claro si tengo alguna duda lo comentare